# express js how to convert an array to an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

This is my user model so you guys can get an idea of my database structure.

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
firstName: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
lastName: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
address: {
    street: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
    city: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
    state: {type: String, min: 2, max: 2, required: false},
    zipCode: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
},
companies:[
    {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Company',
        required: true
    }
],
edited: {type: Date},
created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

I'm trying to get the user and the companies related to that user. which im getting with this.

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){

var email = req.body.email;
var password = req.body.password;


User.findOne({email: email, password: password, active: true})
    .populate('companies')
    .exec(function(err, user){

    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    else if (!user) {
        //user wasn't found
        res.render('/', {validation: "Invalid Email Or Password"})
    }
    else {

        user.companies = user.companies[0];

        console.log(user);

        res.end();

    }

});
});
```

when in the console.log(user) i'm getting this output:

```
{
    firstName: 'firstName',
    lastName: 'lastName'
    companies:[{object}]
}
```

now the problem with my code is that im saying that the companies array should be an object in this line of code.

```
user.companies = user.companies[0];
```

my question is how can I make the console output be like this.

```
    {
    firstName: 'firstName',
    lastName: 'lastName'
    companies:{object}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `user` variable is immutable, you can create another object and copy its data to new object

```
var _user = {
    firstName: user.firstName,
    lastName: user.lastName
    companies: user.companies[0]
}
```

## OR

simply use `toObject()` function to convert mongodb object to plain object, so you can modify it

```
user = user.toObject()
```